# Given a triangle inside a circle, find the horizontal and vertical distance of one of the vertices from the center.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

Given a circle $M$ of known center and radius and a right-angled triangle $JKL$ with one vertex (J) at the circle's center and another vertex (K) at the circle's boundary, find the cartesian coordinates of the third vertex (L) (with respect to the center of the circle). The three sides of the triangle JKL are given, where one of the sides (A) is a radius of the circle. The coordinates for the vertex K are not known.

Background: I intend to move a robotic arm based on x, and y movements to the center of a cylinder, these calculations are needed to determine that.

[image]

Comment: If you know the coordinates of two vertices and sides of the triangle, it is possible to solve this but there will be two possible positions for the third vertex.

Comment: The image shows that the triangle $T$ is a right triangle, do you require that $T$ be a right triangle, or can it be any triangle depending the given side lengths?

Comment: @LexiBelleFan It is a right-angle triangle.

Comment: @Vasya Unfortunately, the coordinates of the two vertices are unknown, but the vertice at the center can be assumed to be on the origin (0,0).

Comment: What do you mean by "known" in the diagram? What is L - the "x" of y? Suggest you improve your question so you could be helped with what seems to be straightforward challenge.

Comment: @Curious94: We have no way to determine the position if only one vertex is known. Imagine triangle nailed at one vertex, you can move it around in a circle. Additional information is needed.

Comment: You write $x,y$ are to be determined. But in the figure both are denoted as "known". Besides it is completely unclear what the symbols refer to. As well as the meaning of the third "known" $z$.

Comment: @Moti I changed the diagram and the question. Please see if it helps.

Comment: @user I changed the diagram and the question. Please check if it is more clear now.

Comment: @Vasya I think you understand the question. The thing is it's not from a book or something, I made it in a way to represent a real-world engineering problem. Is there any assumption, or a constraint we can play with to determine multiple solutions and then choose the best one analytically.

Comment: How are the coordinates of the vertex $K$ given?

Comment: Did you see the linked question? Is not it very similar?

Comment: @user coordinates of the vertex K are not given. Please let me know what led you to this so I can make the change in the question.

Comment: If the coordinates of the vertex $K$ are not given you cannot find the coordinates of the vertex $L$

Comment: The triangle is not ABC. If I understand correct, the triangle is JKL.

Comment: The radius is one of the sides - it seems like repetition. Usually, we prefer not have repetitions since it is confusing - better say "The three sides of the triangle JKL are given, where one of the sides is a radius of the circle..."

Comment: If K coordinates are known, use the distance formula to calculate the coordinates of L.

Comment: @Moti Thanks for your valuable suggestions, I have made the changes to make the question clear and updated the picture as well. The coordinates of K are not known, unfortunately.

Comment: It should be absolutely clear that one cannot find the location of the point $L$ without knowing the location of the point $K$, should not it?

Comment: @user: Is there any assumption, or a constraint we can play with to determine multiple solutions and then choose the best one analytically.

Comment: There is only one parameter which you can determine without knowledge of the position of $K$ - the distance from origin to $L$. In other words it can be any point of the circle.

Comment: L is on a circle with a radius C. As K moves around the A radius circle, L moves on the C radius circle. You may use angels or other relations. You can start with a known location and then follow the movement with certain vectors with small changes - note the movement of L is related to K with the ratio of C/A.

Comment: @Moti Thanks for the comment. I will look more into this!

Answer (score 1):

Let $r$ be the length of $JK,$ $c$ the length of $JL.$ We know the following:

- $K$ is a point on the circle of radius $r$ and center $J.$
- $L$ is a point on the circle of radius $c$ and center $J.$
- $\angle JLK$ is a right angle.

Given any point $K$ on the outer circle, there are two lines passing through $K$ that are tangent to the inner circle, and either of these two points of tangency is a possible location for $L.$ Thus, $K$ could be any point on the outer circle, and even if we know for sure where $K$ is, we can only narrow possible positions for $L$ down to two distinct locations.

On the other hand, given any point $L$ on the inner circle, the tangent line to the inner circle at $L$ intersects the outer circle at exactly two points, and either of these two points of intersection is a possible location for $K.$ Thus, $L$ can theoretically be at any point on the inner circle, and even if we knew exactly where $L$ was, we could only narrow possible locations for $K$ down to two distinct locations.

In conclusion, we need more information to determine the location of $L.$